# Removing Swap Partition after Ubuntu has been installed

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted, swap

So my question is when removing my swap partition sense it is after my boot partition how do I combine it with my root partition? Do I have to run off a Gparted Live cd but how would I go about combining my root and swap without affecting my boot partition? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: @Raphael I think he wants to delete swap partition and enlarge root partition for the same amount of space. However, the problem is that /boot is in between. I don't know whether this is possible and how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THIS IS A HOW-TO TO ANSWER YOUR QUESTION AND HAVE WORKED IN MY SYSTEM BUT IT MIGHT NOT BE TRUE FOR ALL. SO, PROCEED WITH CARE.**

**After you have proceeded with the how-to, it is recommended to type the following command, to be on the safe side**:

```
sudo grub-install --target=i386-pc --boot-directory="/media/<username>/<drive_label>/boot" /dev/sdX
```

**Edit the relevant parts of the command.**

So, you are in a situation that looks something like this:

[image: 1]

**Remeber you need GParted Live CD to do the following if you are doing this on your main drive.**

Now, to do what you asked please follow the steps below:

1. Right-click on `linux-swap` and then, delete.

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

2. Now, right-click on `fat32` or `/dev/sda2` and click on `Resize/Move`.

[image: 4]

3. Next, move the `green box` to the extreme right.

[image: 5]

4. Press, OK for the next window.

[image: 6]

5. Right-click on `ext4` or `/dev/sda1` and select `Resize/Move`.

[image: 7]

6. Fill the `greyed` gap on the extreme right with the blue & white box, then press `Resize`.

[image: 8]

7. Click on `Apply` and wait for it to finish.

[image: 9]

[image: 10]

[image: 11]

8. Click `Close`.

[image: 12]

9. Finally, your partitions will look like this:

[image: 13]

10. Now, you can close and reboot.

Comment: okay ill try this. I shouldn’t have to repair the boot after this right? I know there is always a chance that things might happen but yeah.

Comment: I had one more question does this matter that I'm on an SSD and with UEFI BIOS so I believe its a GTP boot partition that was specially needed for me to install but i don’t know?

Comment: @ichi - Even if its needed, I have provided the command at the start of the Answer to do that.

Comment: @ichi - And no, it doesn't matter.